# Permission denied while updating

Tags: plasma

Whenever I tried to update my system Using

```
sudo apt update && apt upgrade
```

I found this error

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS x86_64 with plasma

Comment: Here, `sudo` was attached to `apt update` not `apt upgrade`. Try running `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`.

Comment: You will have to use `sudo apt update && sudo apt updrade` The way you run it only apt update is run with sudo. The shell the commands on either side of "&&" as different commands.

Comment: @Kulfy, I think you should post your first comment as an answer to the question.